# Horizontal placing of paragraphs with floating text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following with HTML/CSS:
[image: sketch]

The text will come from a Wordpress post, so it can't be any special formatting with it. Post content will have to be with normal `<p>`-tags.

Not sure where to begin, as text will have to float automatically based on different screen sizes aswell.

```
<div class="image">
...image...
</div>
<div class="text">
<p>Paragraph that should split to another paragraph..</p>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is possible with only using HTML/CSS and not modifying the original post content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if the following is what you're actually looking for, but spanning over multiple columns can be done fairly easily with the `column-count` rule. Simply change the number to how many columns you wish to have.

```css
.wrapper {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2; 
  column-count: 2;
}

h1 {
  -webkit-column-span: all; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>How to make text span over multiple columns</h1>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I think [css columns](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_multiple_columns.asp) is the way to go.

```
.text {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I need. Thanks :D